# PayPal Express not giving option for Check out as Guest, even if it is active (PayPal Paying Guest option to YES)

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal, paypal-express

I had some problems with paypal settings in Magento 1.7.0.2.

The problem is this: I am using using paypal express (I have my account created and verified Paypal Company). It has active PayPal Paying Guest option set to YES, but when a user in my shop will complete your purchase and pay with Paypal will be the option PayPal API perfect, but does not show me the option to pay without paypal account. I have VERIFIED ALL settings in Magento Admin Panel and everything "seems to be fine".

I have also tried making a new store to rule out any configuration already had my store "old", that might not let me do my Enable PayPal Guest Checkout, but still have the same problem. I look forward to your help to solve the problem, since I have no idea what else to do on my page. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to do is to make sure that your call to paypal includes `SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole` as this should be the flag to inform paypal to allow guest checkouts.

1. If this flag is not set then you can investigate the Magento side to see why this is not being set of request,
2. If this is set but set to `Mark` then your config value is set to not allow guest checkout from the Magento admin config,
3. If this value is set then I would suggest there is a problem on the paypal side of things and would recommend getting in contact with them directly,

I hope this helps you find your issue.

Comment: where i can set SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole in magento 2.3?